# How can I access a non power of 2 resizable memory in a shader(OpenGL 4.0)?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I need to use a block of memory in a fragment shader. I've read about GL_TEXTURE_1D, but I've read that maximum size could be low. This block of memory will change its size at runtime and this size should be at least 1MB.
I will access this block sequentially in a fragment shader:

```
for (int i=0; i<sizeOfBlock; i++){
     vec4 v=read(block, i);
}
```

I guess that this shader will be very slow even though the FBO is 256x256, but I hope that it can run at 5-10 fps in a gtx 550 Ti, ¿is it impossible?

Which OpenGL object should I choose to use this memory?

Comment: Are you really want to do kinf od a _million_ memory fetches in a single fragment shader invocation? I guess that this will be  much slower than the 5 to 10 fps you are hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into buffer textures. Their supported size is guaranteed to be at least 65536 pixels, which does not quite meet your requirements. But I believe most GPUs support much larger sizes. The supported size can be queried with `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE`.

You can find a complete description at http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Texture. To summarize the most important steps in using a buffer texture:

- Store your data in a buffer, with the usual `glGenBuffers()`, `glBindBuffer()`, `glBufferData()` calls.
- Create a texture id with `glGenBuffers()`.
- Bind the texture with `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, id)`.
- Use `glTexBuffer()` to associate your buffer data with the texture.
- In the fragment shader, declare a uniform variable of type `samplerBuffer` for the texture, and access the data with the `texelFetch()` function.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want.